# Changing the parameter submitted for a Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have a drop-down form that contains 4 different types of IDs which then queries a database. How do I change the parameter which is submitted to the action page? It always submits the same input name rather than the value selected in the dropdown box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way how HTML forms work. The `name=value` pair of an input element will be sent, not its ID. You should also rather be interested in the parameter value instead of the parameter name. So instead of a hypothetical and horrific approach like this

```
if (request.getParameter("foo1") != null) {
    results = service.find("foo1");
} else if (request.getParameter("foo2") != null) {
    results = service.find("foo2");
} else if (request.getParameter("foo3") != null) {
    results = service.find("foo3");
} else if (request.getParameter("foo4") != null) {
    results = service.find("foo4");
}
```

you should just do

```
results = service.find(request.getParameter("foo"));
```

in combination with

```html
<select name="foo">
    <option value="foo1">foo 1</option>
    <option value="foo2">foo 2</option>
    <option value="foo3">foo 3</option>
    <option value="foo4">foo 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `<form name="dropdown" method=post action="LDAPSearch.jsp" target ="info">
 <select name="inputType">
 <option value="uid">UID</option>
 <option value="did">DID</option>
 <option value="cidx">CIDX</option>
 <option value="roleid">RoleID</option>
</select>
 <input type="text" name="ldapInput">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: Your point being? Just get the selected value by `request.getParameter("inputType")`?